# Change fixed height to variable height when using TabBarViews

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with tabBarViews and I currently have set the container height to:

```
 //TODO: change to dynamic height
 content: Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8, child: _tabBarBodyViews()),
```

I would like to set my height to a variable height with an expanded or flexible. I am not sure how to accomplish that because when I put an expanded or flexible it throws RenderBox errors.

This is my full code:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingDetailPersonButton(viewModel),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: viewModel.scrollController,
          child: Container(
            
            child: _doctorInformationTabBar(context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

 DefaultTabController _doctorInformationTabBar(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 6,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          StickyHeader(
            header: Column(
              children: [
                DetallePersonaHeader(viewModel: viewModel),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: kHeaderColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  ),
                  child: _tabBar(context),
                ),
              ],
            ), 
            //TODO: This has a strange behavior, it should be fixed
            content: Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8, child: _tabBarBodyViews()),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TabBarView _tabBarBodyViews() {
    return TabBarView(children: [
      VisitGeneralInformationTab(viewModel: viewModel),
      VisitListTab(viewModel: viewModel),
      AccPromoTab(viewModel: viewModel),
      InteractionsTab(),
      AuditoryTab(viewModel: viewModel),
      QuizTab(viewModel: viewModel)
    ]);
  }
}
```

As you can see my `_tabBarBodyViews` has TabBarViews. Each view have dynamic height depending on API content. I can set a `size.height * 4` but this would give me a big blank space on shorter views.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't have expanded in _singlechildscrollview_. Remove **singlechildscrollview** and used expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CustomScrollView` and add a list of `slivers`. For example:

```
const List<Tab> tabs = [Tab(...), Tab(...)];
final TabController controller = TabController(...);

CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              onTap: (int index) {
                if (onTap != null) {
                  onTap!(index: index, tabs: tabs);
                }
              },
              labelPadding: labelPadding,
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: tabs,
              controller: controller,
              unselectedLabelColor: unselectedLabelColor,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
),
```

That ought to get you in the right ballpark. Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full context of your code, but I do know Expanded is probably what you're going for here, yeah.

The key is to make sure that Expanded is *always* placed directly inside of a Row, Column, or Flex. But then along with that, the flex/column/row has a direct parent that has a specific/bounded HEIGHT and WIDTH. Expanded will expand in both directions even if it's placed specifically for example in a column (so you might be fooled into thinking it will only expand in height).

Perhaps something like this:

```
content: Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - actualPixelHeightOfHeader,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: _tabBarBodyViews(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

You might need to fiddle around with different values for the height of the container if you don't know the exact height of the header.

Comment: But what if my tabBarBodyVeiws have dynamic height depending on my data from the api? I don't want to set a fixed height with a mediaquery. Because my items can be 4 or can be 100

Comment: In this case you could place them inside of a SingleChildScrollView and give the scroll view the height of MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - actualPixelHeightOfHeader